# Реализация функции mconcat c использованием fold expressions

Tags: c++, haskell, функциональное-программирование

Определение функции [mconcat](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:mconcat):

```
mconcat :: Monoid a => [a] -> a
mconcat = foldr mappend mempty
```

Реализация [foldr](https://wiki.haskell.org/Data.Foldable.foldr):

```
template<typename F, typename T>
decltype(auto) foldr(F, T arg) { return arg; }

template<typename F, typename T, typename ...Ts>
decltype(auto) foldr(F f, T init, T head, Ts ...tail)
{
    return f(head, foldr(f, init, tail...));
}
```

Реализация mconcat:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Ts>
decltype(auto) mconcat(T head, Ts ...tail)
{
    return foldr(&mappend<T>, mempty<T>(), head, tail...);
}
```

Можно ли вместо функции foldr использовать [fold-expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)? В описании указан необходимый вариант свертки - правая, с бинарным оператором, однако, я не могу придумать, каким образом можно заменить его на вызов функции mappend, или, наоборот, как реализовать wrapper для mappend так, чтобы его можно было использовать как бинарный оператор.

Comment: Для желающих закрыть вопрос: не совсем понимаю, почему в качестве причины вы указываете "не по теме"? Мне не нужно помогать с отладкой :) У меня есть теоретический вопрос, который вполне себе имеет право на существование, если вы считаете иначе - будьте добры, объясните.

Comment: А разве причина закрытия в развернутом виде не видна?

Comment: @VTT, разумеется, нет. Если Вы голосовали за закрытие - объясните, пожалуйста, что не так.

Comment: Почему "разумеется"? Там должна быть видна причина в развернутом виде. Не зря же эта развернутая причина указывается. А что у вас за браузер?

Comment: @VTT, извините, не так Вас понял. Причину я вижу, и в первом комментарии я ее озвучил. На мой взгляд - это необоснованный выбор, потому как, во-первых, отлаживать мне ничего не нужно, а во-вторых - конкретная проблема есть, и описана она в последнем абзаце.

Comment: Вопрос "Можно ли вместо функции foldr использовать fold-expressions?" лишен смысла. Если имеется поддержка C++17 и результат работы fold-expressions устраивает, то можно. Если вы хотите получить что-то конкретное, то опишите желаемое поведение и что там не получается с fold-expressions. Причем примеры должны быть самодостаточными и воспроизводимыми, чтобы людям не приходилось гадать, что там у вас скрывается за `&mappend<T>`.

Comment: @VTT, нет, не лишен. Верните его в исходный контекст - и оно обретет смысл. Перейдите по ссылкам, которые я специально оставил для тех, кто мог ни разу с этим не сталкиваться - и Вам станет понятно, что и за чем скрывается. Только Вы этого не сделаете. Ведь в противном случае у Вас не останется времени на просмотр и закрытие других вопросов, а это чревато "не получением" очередной ачивки.

Comment: Как и указано на cpp, для использования fold-expression нужно использовать какой-либо бинарный оператор. Вы можете перегрузить для нужных вам типов какой-нибудь оператор, в котором будете делегировать операцию функции mappend и тогда уже использовать fold expression